# How to add a decorator at left of a single paragraph in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

I have a custom `UITextView`, and I have several styles for it.

One of them includes adding a **vertical line** all to the left besides the actual text for an specific paragraph. This line should have the same size as the paragraph and scroll with it.

How can this be achieved using `UITextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can take another approach for your problem by add a `UIView` or `CALayer` with a filled background to the left of your UITextView. Just set its width value to 2-3 to equate it as the 'left border'.

```
extension UITextView {
    func setLeftBorder(color: UIColor, width:CGFloat = 2.0) {
        let borderFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: self.frame.width)
        let borderView = UIView(frame: borderFrame)
        borderView.backgroundColor = color
        self.addSubview(borderView)
    }
}
```

But the problem will not solved when your UITextView starts scrolling. So I think you should embed them together inside another `UIView`. Here is my final solution by using AutoLayout:
[My Solution - Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huyAs.png)

Comment: I'm making a TextEditor, so, it's imperative that this decorator can be able to change it´s size and to scroll along with the text